# Calling export in foreach loop

Tags: recursion, makefile

I am tying to pass variables to sub makefiles via `export`

The main Makefile contains a list of components `COMPONENT_LIST` that will be compiled. In the rule of the target `all` I exported the `USE_COMP_1`, `USE_COMP_2`and `USE_COMP_3` variables using `foreach` function:

```
COMPONENT_LIST:=\
COMP_1\
COMP_2\
COMP_3


all:
    $(foreach comp,$(COMPONENT_LIST),export USE_$(comp)=y;)     
    @for comp in $(COMPONENT_LIST) ; do \
        make -C $$comp all; \
        if [ ! $$? -eq 0 ]; then \
            echo "component \"$$comp\" not found. Please make sure that folder \"$$comp\" exist";\
            exit 1; \
        fi \
    done
```

But in the sub Makefile The value of `USE_COMP_1`, `USE_COMP_2`and `USE_COMP_3` is empty.

Is there any explanation to this ?

Comment: You are using the shell command `export`. You could use the Make directive `export`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

**every sub-command is run in its own shell**

So I missed the the `\`

```
all:
    $(foreach comp,$(COMPONENT_LIST),export USE_$(comp)=y;)\
    for comp in $(COMPONENT_LIST) ; do \
        make -C $$comp all; \
        if [ ! $$? -eq 0 ]; then \
            echo "component \"$$comp\" not found. Please make sure that folder \"$$comp\" exist";\
            exit 1; \
        fi \
    done
```

In this case the `export` and the following for loop are run in the same shell